# Chosen module present but inactive

Tags: views

[image]

To replicate the issue:

Install and enable Chosen module ->

(Apply Chosen to exposed filter)

Add `.views-widget-filter-title` to /config/user-interface/chosen under                 "Apply Chosen to the following elements"

Why is my chosen element present but inactive? (See picture)

Answer (score 0):

The selector added to "Apply Chosen to the following elements" section would be

```
.view-filters .views-exposed-form select
```

in order for Chosen plugin to be applied to Views exposed filter with select drop-down widget.

Comment: Thanks! That didn't seem to do the trick though... Is there some other condition that needs to be met to get chosen working?

Comment: Set min and max options to "Always apply" also if you have more than one custom selector added, make sure they are separated by commas. And it is always good to clear Drupal's cache.